# get select value in controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I need to get the Select value in the controller

strDDLValue in the variable " "

I tried to do it, but it does not work

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AddItemViewModel model, IFormCollection form)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string strDDLValue = Request.Form["selectCategory"].ToString();
```

html

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" id="selectCategory">

</select>
```

Autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Item/GetItemCategories',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (category) {
                $.each(category, function (key, value) {
                    $('#selectCategory')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value",key)
                        .text(value)); 
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "*does not work*"?

Comment: strDDLValue in the variable ""

Comment: So how do you submit your form? The action method you've shown us, is not decorated with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: hung up [HttpPost]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you populate the select tag helper correctly in the callback of ajax . Here is the working example:

the controller of GetCountry and the success function in ajax

```
public JsonResult GetCountry()
    {
        var country =  _context.Country.ToList();
        return Json(new SelectList(country,"Id","CountryName"));

    }

success: function (result) {
                $("#selectCountry").empty();
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    $("#selectCountry").append('<option value="' + item.value + '"> ' + item.text + ' </option>');
                });
```

Specify the `name` attribute  of the select tag helper to be filled

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="selectCountry"  id="selectCountry">  </select>
```

Form-data are saved as the key-value pair in the request , you could get the value of selectCountry like below

```
var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());

//In that case, you could iterate over your dictionary or you can access values directly:
var ddl = dict["selectCountry"];
```